# Installing cURL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, dependencies, apt

Am trying to install cURL on my ubuntu server using the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

However i get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-curl: Depends: phpapi-20060613+lfs
Depends: php5-common (= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.5) but 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am running **PHP Version 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1** on my server.
Whats the issue? I need to get curl up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have installed `php5-common` from the [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repository, but Dotdeb do not provide a `php5-curl` package. You either need to replace PHP with the version from the official Ubuntu repositories, or you need to build php5-curl yourself against the Dotdeb version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package is broken in your source.

Maybe you can test this:

> apt-get install curl

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may want run this command `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little and tell us why this would solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: `apt-get update` refreshes your server's package list from the mirrors, ensuring you don't download old packages and that there are new inconsistencies in your package database.